# Hijacking the Meteor accounts-ui logout button

Tags: meteor, package, overriding

I am using the `accounts-ui` package for Meteor to create a Sign-up/Log-in widget. I want users who are not signed in to be able to continue to use my app anonymously, so I want to detect when a user signs out.

As far as I can tell, there is a way to [register a function when the user logs in](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) but no similar event is triggered when the user logs out. The next best thing is the [`Meteor.logout(\[callback\])`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_logout) command, which accepts a callback function.

I have found the following lines of code in `/Users/<name>/.meteor/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/.1.1.8.cfkrwq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/web.browser/login_buttons.js`

```
Template.loginButtons.events({ 
  'click #login-buttons-logout': function() {
    Meteor.logout(function () {
      loginButtonsSession.closeDropdown();
    });
  }
});
```

I want to add a call to a method of my own here, but I don't want this method to be called in all the projects where I use accounts-ui. I understand that I could copy the `accounts-ui-unstyled/` folder to the packages folder at the root of this project, and modify it there, but then I will miss any updates that may be delivered for the package.

What is the best-practice method of intercepting the log-out call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is just to track the logged-in state in a `Tracker`:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if ( Meteor.userId() ){
    ... do things for a logged-in user
  } else {
    ... do things for a logged-out user
  }
});
```

This autorun block will run automatically whenever the login state changes as `Meteor.userId()` is a reactive data source.

Comment: I get this error: `Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions`. However, if I replace `Meteor` with `this`, I get `Cannot call method 'userId' of null`. : |

Comment: This is meant to run client-side. Either wrap it with `Meteor.isClient` or put the js under `/client`